# c# returning error “not all code paths return a value” when using this method

Tags: c#

I wants to use this method to convert 3 letter dates from the database. But its returning an error when I created it, this method should display the corresponding number of the 3 letter date in the output. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

```
public static string MonthConvert(string input)
        {
            string month1 = "";
            string month3 = "";
            string result = "";
            month3 = input;
            if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("JAN"))
                month1 = "01/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("FEB"))
                month1 = "02/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("MAR"))
                month1 = "03/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("APR"))
                month1 = "04/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("MAY"))
                month1 = "05/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("JUN"))
                month1 = "06/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("JUL"))
                month1 = "07/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("AUG"))
                month1 = "08/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("SEP"))
                month1 = "09/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("OCT"))
                month1 = "10/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("NOV"))
                month1 = "11/";
            else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("DEC"))
                month1 = "12/";
            result = month1.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You are missing Return result;

Comment: You should be looking for `DateTime.Parse` instead of writing this method... If you really want help with this code - make sure to read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly.

Comment: Return something from the method will remove error.

Answer (score 1):

If a `function` return type is not `void`, then the function must return a value. In your code the `function` return type is `string` but it is not returning anything (means - you didn't mention `return` statement at the last line of the function. Modify your code like below.

```
public static string MonthConvert(string input)
{
    string month1 = "";
    string month3 = "";
    string result = "";
    month3 = input;
    if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("JAN"))
        month1 = "01/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("FEB"))
        month1 = "02/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("MAR"))
        month1 = "03/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("APR"))
        month1 = "04/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("MAY"))
        month1 = "05/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("JUN"))
        month1 = "06/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("JUL"))
        month1 = "07/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("AUG"))
        month1 = "08/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("SEP"))
        month1 = "09/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("OCT"))
        month1 = "10/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("NOV"))
        month1 = "11/";
    else if (month3.ToUpper().Equals("DEC"))
        month1 = "12/";
    result = month1;
    return month1;
}
```

Comment: This works.  It would be best to eliminate result altogether.

Comment: *If a function return type is not `void`, then the function must return a value.* `int F() { throw new Exception(); }` or `int G() { for(;;); }` does not return anything, but do not cause any compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest modifying your approach.  Instead of even building this function, look at this snippet:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        var testVals = new[] {"Jan", "FEB", "mar", "bad"};

        foreach (var v in testVals)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(v.ToUpper(),
                "MMM",
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, // you may want new CultureInfo("en-US") if you intend only English values to pass.
                DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
                out dt))
                Console.WriteLine($"{v} returns {dt.Month}");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"{v} failed parsing.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

No need to reinvent the wheel when .NET has it done.

If you're determined you need this function, try this:

```
    public static string MonthConvert(string input)
    {
        if (input == null) return "";   //Otherwise you'll get a NullReferenceException - which you probably should let be thrown.

        if (input.Equals("JAN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "01/";
        if (input.Equals("FEB", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "02/";
        if (input.Equals("MAR", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "03/";
        if (input.Equals("APR", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "04/";
        if (input.Equals("MAY", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "05/";
        if (input.Equals("JUN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "06/";
        if (input.Equals("JUL", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "07/";
        if (input.Equals("AUG", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "08/";
        if (input.Equals("SEP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "09/";
        if (input.Equals("OCT", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "10/";
        if (input.Equals("NOV", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "11/";
        if (input.Equals("DEC", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return "12/";

        return ""; //You should really consider throwing an ArgumentException, here. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be brief, I'm writing this on a phone, but as others have indicated, the error message is exactly correct: you don't return anything at all because there's no return statement.

In general, it's helpful to look carefully at the text of the error message in cases like that and understand why the compiler is telling you that. In this case, the question is "under what circumstances will it *not* return anything?" The techniques described in [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) can be helpful here, especially "rubber-duck debugging" - for example, try to explain why your program will obviously return something in every case until you reach a case you can't explain. The case you can't explain is probably your error.)

I'd also strongly suggest using a switch statement here instead of repeated if...else if statements - it'll be a lot easier to read. Also, you're currently doing a lot more casts than you actually need to - you're repeatedly converting the string to uppercase when you only need to do that once.